# Parse Classes with similar names using Beautiful Soup in python

Tags: html, python-2.7, class, beautifulsoup, findall

I have an html page from which I want to extract the `td` element with the class attribute `bold`. Instead other td elements pop up like `dark bold`

When I use the findAll method in BeautifulSoup,

```
scores= soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == 'td', { "class" : "bold"})
```

I get all these elements

```
 <td class="dark bold">
    <span class="hide-for-tablet">Sebastian</span>
    <span class="hide-for-mobile">Vettel</span>
    <span class="uppercase hide-for-desktop">VET</span>
    </td>
    <td class="bold hide-for-mobile">78</td>
    <td class="dark bold">1:44:44.340</td>
    <td class="bold">25</td>
```

Where as all I really want is

`<td class="bold">25</td>`

How do I narrow down my results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
scores= soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == 'td' and tag.get('class') == ['bold'])
```

Comment: @HideoDaikoku Thank you